# What is $\cos^2(t) + \sin^2(-t)$?

Tags: trigonometry

The question is straight forward, what is

$$\cos^2(t) + \sin^2(-t)$$?

I know $\cos^2(t) + \sin^2(t) = 1 $, but I don't know what it gives when there is a minus in one and plus in the other. I have tried googling, but I found no answer.

Thank you for answering :)

Comment: Do you know how $\sin t$ and $\sin (-t)$ are related?

Comment: Yes I do, I was doing a problem in Calculus 3. I am pretty stressed and my mind is not working atm; I have my final exam tomorrow. I feel kind of dumb now lol.

Comment: We all have such days. Be sure to have a good sleep before tomorrow.

Comment: You're a good dude, thanks for the support. I sure will :)

Comment: It's useful to remember that $\sin x$ is an odd function, while $\cos x$ is even.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** $$\sin(-x)=-\sin(x)\qquad\text{for all }x\in\Bbb R.$$

---

**Intuition:** [image: sorry for the bad quality]

<sub><sub>Sorry for the bad quality, I only have access to Paint for the moment.</sub></sub>

Comment: Thank you for the hint Hakim. When I saw this I felt pretty dumb.

Comment: @JohnMadon1234567890 You're welcome, I've added a part explaining the intuition behind that formula so that you never feel dumb again. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Since $\sin(-t) = -\sin(t)$ then $\sin^2(-t) = \sin^2(t)$ hence $\cos^2(t) + \sin^2(t) = 1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) I knew it was pretty straight forward but my mind is not working right now.